# Decrypt String with *.Pem file in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, pem, x509certificate2

Ok, I have a string of text, encoded in Base64.

I want to decode this from Base64 to a byte array, then decrypt this with my private key. My private key is a *.pem file. I am lost!

I think I need to declare a byte array, grab the text between the ---BEGIN--- and ---END--- part of my *.pem, and convert this from a base 64 string as the result of my byte array.

I then need to declare an X509Certificate2, and use the constructor that takes a byte array and a string of text, the byte array being my private key, the string of text being my passphrase like below:

```
byte[] myprivateKey = Convert.FromBase64String("BASE 64 ENCODED PRIVATE KEY GOES HERE");
X509Certificate2 myPem = new X509Certificate2(myprivateKey, "MY PASSPHRASE");
```

However, I am getting the following error at this point:

> Cannot find the requested object.

Am I heading in the right direction at least or am I way off? What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X509Certificate2` won't read a private key from a **PEM** base64-encoded file. You'll need to read the private key apart from the certificate and then assign it the the `PrivateKey` property.

See [how to get private key from PEM file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400500/how-to-get-private-key-from-pem-file) for more details.

Comment: Thankyou, this is really helpful, however where do I find "ASN1" and "X509ExtensionCollection"? As in which references do I need to use? Thankyou

Comment: This is all part of Mono.Security.dll (which is part of Mono but works with MS.NET too). Full source code is available from https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security

Comment: Sorry I have one more question, is there an actual DLL file that I can download and add to my project? Or do I need to download the project at this link and add this? Thankyou

Comment: AFAIK the binary .dll is not downloadable by itself. But it does exists in all the Mono runtime downloads for Win32 (and inside other projects that re-use it). Otherwise you can copy-paste the sources/files that you require in your own application.