# Generating keyPair using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, bouncycastle

I have Java code for generating keypair using BC as follows:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(1024);
KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey priv = key.getPrivate();
PublicKey pub = key.getPublic();
String privateKey = new String(Base64.encode(priv.getEncoded(), 0,priv.getEncoded().length, Base64.NO_WRAP));
String publicKey1 = new String(Base64.encode(pub.getEncoded(), 0,pub.getEncoded().length, Base64.NO_WRAP));
String publicKey = new String(Base64.encode(publicKey1.getBytes(),0, publicKey1.getBytes().length, Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

Now I want to do same in C# using BC. I have downloaded WP8BouncyCastle library via nuget package manager. I have written as:

```
var kpgen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();

kpgen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), 1024));

var keyPair = kpgen.GenerateKeyPair();
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = keyPair.Private;
AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = keyPair.Public;


string prvKey = Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey.ToString()));
string pubKey = Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publicKey.ToString()));
string pubKey1 = Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pubKey.ToString()));
```

But I need `getEncoded()` method available in Java which is not available in BC library in C#. This `getEncoded()` method is used to convert given key into  X.509 encoded key.In case of Java, public key getting twice converted (`getencoded()` and `getBytes()`) ,I am not able to do same in C#.

Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following code for private key:

```
PrivateKeyInfo pkInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(keyPair.Private);
String privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(pkInfo.GetDerEncoded());
```

and following for public:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo info = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyPair.Public);
String publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(info.GetDerEncoded());
```

Comment: I got it from other blog.Anyways thanx.

Comment: You could at least post the blog link :/

Comment: Namespaces:
Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo, Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfoFactory, Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory

Comment: Build the X509 Certificate: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory