# CryptographicException in RSA.ImportParameters() - Bad Data in special 1024 keys

Tags: c#, rsa, private-key, cryptographicexception

We have a C#/.Net 4.0 application which imports RSA Private Keys from a String in Base64 received in a WebService.

This application works perfectly for RSA-Keys in 1024 bits, but doesn't with a special kind of rsa private keys (around 1% of keys).

Here are the byte lengths:

Working-Key:

- Modulus => 128 Bytes
- Exponent => 3 Bytes
- D => 128 Bytes
- P => 64 Bytes
- Q => 64 Bytes
- DP => 64 Bytes
- DQ => 64 Bytes
- IQ => 64 Bytes

Not-Working-Key:

- Modulus => 128 Bytes
- Exponent => 3 Bytes
- **D => 127 Bytes**
- P => 64 Bytes
- Q => 64 Bytes
- DP => 64 Bytes
- DQ => 64 Bytes
- IQ => 64 Bytes

The difference is in the lenght of D (128 working, 127 not working). The not-working key is 1 byte shorter than the working key.

The parameters are set but when doing RSA.ImportParameters(rsaParams) it throws a CryptographicException with a "Bad Data" Message.

What should be included to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` has some assumptions on the data lengths which are:

- Modulus: any even size, let's call the length `n`
- Exponent: (`<= 4` bytes; though RSACng allows "any size"), let's call the length `e`
- D: `n`
- P: `n/2`
- Q: `n/2`
- DP: `n/2`
- DQ: `n/2`
- InverseQ: `n/2`

So, assuming that your second key is actually Modulus: 128 bytes (because a 64-byte P times a 64-byte Q isn't a 256 byte number), you just need to left-pad the D array with a zero to bring it up to the proper length.

```
byte[] newD = new byte[modulus.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(d, 0, newD, newD.Length - d.Length, d.Length);
```

.NET Core has the [source code available](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/bddba0dcf2decd22900f1a8a0944408d3b852fd5/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Csp/src/System/Security/Cryptography/CapiHelper.cs#L953-L972) showing that relationship.  In .NET Framework it's buried inside the CLR, so not available on referencesource.

Comment: Yep. This usually forms because `D` is stored in as an `INTEGER` in ASN.1, and ASN.1 encoding rules specify that integers must be encoded in the shortest form possible. So in those cases where an integer is < the required size, it's likely because the integer has insignificant zeros.