# Create private RSA key from String object

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, jwt, adal

I am trying to create a custom jwt token for firebase authentication from a C# WCF service. The problem is that I need to sign the jwt token with my private RSA key (e.g. "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBA ... wFg=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----).

How do I create a representation of the private key in String format (in brackets above) to a representation that C# understands?

Comment: are the \n in the Key String or representative of line breaks?

Comment: They are new lines as it is a RSA private key.

Comment: Then I really don't understand the question. If you already know the key and just need to place it in a string then it just needs to be wrapped in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I konw, [X509Certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) is not able to read a private key from a PEM base64-encoded file.

It is more easily to read the private key from the certificates. And refer to [how to get private key from PEM file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400500/how-to-get-private-key-from-pem-file) about the detail.

Comment: Yes, i did see the link above, thanks for your input.