# Is there a 100% managed way to create an X509 certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, x509, .net-standard

## Edit:

Turns out that [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) is fully managed. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755155/store-pkcs12-container-pfx-with-bouncycastle) explains how to create a .pfx file with a private and public part of the certificate.

---

For an application that I'm writing in C# (targeting .net Standard 2.0/.net Core 2.x), I want to create X509Certificates with a private key, basically a self-signed HTTPS certificate with RSA and SHA256 or SHA512.

I know how to do this through the Windows API with `CertCreateSelfSignCertificate` from Crypt32.dll, but I wonder if there is a 100% managed solution for this?

This is for dev use, so the fact that the cert isn't trusted is no issue. I don't want to execute an external application (openssl), and even though .net Core has some native crypto bindings, I'm looking for fully managed.

Comment: CertificateRequest (in the linked answer) is part of .NET Core 2.0.  There's no (inbox) pure managed solution for .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Framework 4.7.

Comment: If it's for dev use and you don't mind it not being trusted, then why bother with c#-created certs? Create them externally via a tool.  For that matter, why bother with certs at all? Sounds like it is going to be running on a trusted, non-public environment anyway?

Comment: @MickyD In this case, it's not for HTTPS cert but to prototype and test a certificate-based encryption protocol. So I need certificates, and I need to dynamically create them for each test.

Comment: No problem good sir

Comment: CertificateRequest is available now in an early access build of .NET 4.7.2: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/05/announcing-net-framework-4-7-2-early-access-build-3052/