# How to load PEM certificate in powershell 5?

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

I already have pemfile with private key inside.
I try to do smth like this [how to get private key from PEM file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400500/how-to-get-private-key-from-pem-file)
but I have stuck when create certificate object from file

in short:

```
$SourceCertificateFile= gc "E:\PSW\test.pem"
$EncCert=[Convert]::FromBase64String( ($SourceCertificate)[1..($SourceCertificate.Count -2 )] -as [string] )

New-Object   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate( @(, $EncCert)) #doesn`t work -Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): object not found

New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 ($EncCert) #Cannot find an overload for "X509Certificate2" and the argument count: "1104"

[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($SourceCertificateFile) #doesn`t work -Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): object not found

$x=[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::New()
$x.Import($EncCert) #Exception calling "Import" with "1" argument(s): object not found
```

I see that exist X509Certificate2Collection.ImportFromPemFile method, but I don't understand how to properly initialize constructor

Thanks for any suggestions

pem files generated on linux host as

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
```

PEM File (fresh generated):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: your file is not a certificate, it is PKCS#1 RSA key. There is no certificate in file.

Comment: @Crypt32, 
RSA.ImportFromPem method is not available (why?)
$rsa= [System.Security.Cryptography.RSA]::Create()
$rsa.ImportFromPem($pem)  get error "The method call failed because [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider] does not have a method named "ImportFromPem".

Comment: This method is available in .NET 5.0, thus PowerShell Core with .NET 5 is required. PowerShell 5 does not support .NET 5.0.

Answer (score -1):

Your file is an RSA private key, not a certificate.

You'd load something like that with something like

```cs
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportFromPem(File.ReadAllText("private.pem"));
    // use the key here.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in powershell 5 as mentioned in the question.